# Writing to an excel file depending upon adjacent column value

Tags: c#, excel, linq-to-sql

I have some data in an excel sheet like

```
Id     Name    Result   Address
1      ABC              123-Plot 2
2      XYZ              234-Street 45
```

Here right now the Result Col is left blank.

I have a C# application which will calculate the result of the students based on the mark they have secured.

Now i want to write the result of each student back to the excel sheet from my application.
I will he having the Id of the student(which is col1 here) and the result(to be written in col 3).

Please tell me appropriate ways to do it.

I looked for it a little,but havent got the solution .

Please help. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what you've tried so far?

Comment: Lacking some detail: how are you reading from/writing to the sheet?

Comment: Why dont you just read the pre poluated excel sheet into a datatable and then write all `Results` and again write that data to another excel file and save it?

Comment: Plesae check my other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22678486/unable-to-write-data-to-excel-using-oledb